# Controllability matrix cannot be defined $\implies$ the system cannot be controllable?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, linear-control

Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $A=\lambda I$, for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that a necessarily condition for the controllability of $(A,B)$ is $m\ge n$.

I assume this means for $$A=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_{2} & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_{n}\end{bmatrix} \qquad B=\begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1m} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ b_{n1} & \cdots & b_{nm}\end{bmatrix}$$

Is it sufficient to state that the controllability matrix cannot be defined for $m<n$, since in order to compute the controllability matrix, we must compute $A\cdot b$, which cannot be done if $m<n$?...Or maybe I've misinterpreted the question?

Comment: I think the bottom-right lambda has the wrong subscript (1 instead of n)? I'll let you edit it since I'm not sure.

Comment: @lifesayko Yes, I just edited that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your interpretation of the question may be incomplete. It is usually assumed that $ A \in  \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ and $ B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$.

The [controllability matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability#Continuous_linear_time-invariant_.28LTI.29_systems) ( assuming a linear time invaraint system) can be defined as

$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}B & AB & A^2B & \cdots & A^{n-1}B \end{bmatrix}
$$

and the system $ ( A, B) $ is controllable if $ C $ has full rank $ rank(C) = n $.

The rank of a matrix is the maximum number of linearly independent rows or columns. If $ m > n $ this means that $ rank(B) \leq n$.

From your description we know that $A $ is full rank, $ rank(A) = n$.

The [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) of the product of two matrices obeys

$$
rank(AB) \leq \min(rank(A),rank(B))
$$

Combining all of this means that your system is only controllable if $ B $ is full rank. One intuitive way to think of this is having enough control inputs to control each of your states. Having a surplus of control inputs ($ m > n$) does not improve controllability.

Finally, $m<n$ is possible because the matrix product $ AB$ is well defined as long as $ B $ has $ n $ rows.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if $m>n$, then $\text{rank}(B)\le n$ Then you write that the system is only controllable if $B$ is of full rank, i.e. $\text{rank}(B)=n$. But the question is asking to show that $m\ge n$ is a necessarily condition of controllability, so I'm sensing a contradiction somewhere.